# Was iron important for the first life on Earth?

Tags: evolution, biochemistry, life-history

Some ions or compounds are thought not to have become involved or important in the metabolism of living organisms until some time after certain mutations took place. For instance, early life is thought to selectively allow calcium ions through its membrane, but eventually also evolved the ability to selectively allow sodium ions, specifically through a mutation that lead to a change in the composition of a channel protein from glutamine to lysine.

Currently, iron is involved in oxidations involving molecular oxygen, such as in cytochromes and clearly holds a key role in modern life, despite that free iron or even ferric compounds are rarely accessible. From my understanding, iron most likely became incorporated into the metabolism of microbes after during/after aerobic organisms had developed, but this does not rule out the possibility that iron was involved earlier on. So, I am wondering if iron was involved in early life, and details on how would be appreciated.

Comment: "a mutation in the structure of amino acids to form lysine"? How exactly does a chemical compound mutate? I would stick to your question and avoid unscientific analogies and unprovable remarks about when different amino acids emerged.

Comment: @David since most biological compounds used in life are produced through a genetically control process, saying "X mutated" is a common acceptable shorthand for saying "the genes that controls the production of X mutated changing the structure of X".

Comment: @John I dont know in what circles is that acceptable, maybe creationists, but if my student wrote something like this on an exam, I would fail him on the spot - and that would be mercy in comparison what my master or phd advisors would do to him. Structure of a chemical compound cannot mutate, period. If you add or remove an atom from the structure of a chemical compound, it becomes a different compound.

Also, the title is misleading. Asking IF iron was important for the first life on earth is not the same thing as asking WHEN did the iron become important.

Comment: I am afraid what you write is neither accepted by or acceptable to professional scientists. Nor can a clause evoking a mechanism be shorthand for the simple statement such as “lysine emerged later” — indeed it is a clear violation of Occam’s Razor. It unjustifiably and unnecessarily implies a knowledge of the order of addition of amino acids to the genetic code, the mechanism by which the code expanded, and some sort of ‘purpose’ in relation to ion transport. I have edited your question to make it scientifically acceptable and appropriate to the question.

Comment: @david are you not aware cells will modify amino acids, this is how the majority of amino acids are produced after all. Post-translational modification of animo acids is fairly common.

Comment: John, I have taken the time to provide a detailed chemical answer to the title of your question (which I did not alter). You might care to direct your attention to that. Do you understand it? Does it seem satisfactory? Have you any comments on it?

Comment: I think it's inappropriate for you to make such a large change like that. Life relied on calcium, then selectively included sodium. I wanted to know if the same kind of thing happened with iron and how in order to track the timeline of the incorporation of different elements for microbial evolution, and my original question got me an answer. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24517213

Comment: The reinsertion of a revised first paragraph is unnecessary, misleading and a poor analogy for your question. First, you are not asking if iron replaced some other metal or system — or if you meant to do so it is not evident in your question. Second you talk about the acquisition of sodium channels from calcium in “early life”, when the paper you refer to talks about the evolution of the channels in eukaryotes. It would be far more pertinent to expend your effort on justifying your assertion of “iron being rarely accessible" — something that my own answer argues was not necessarily true.

Comment: I don't think it's misleading at all, I think you're being too technical (if your assertion is even accurate) where it isn't relevant. What I proposed is an example of the kind of phenomena I am referring where life evolved to incorporate another element and in an understandable way, which continued to happen with more elements like molybdenum, copper, iodine and more. The paper talks about life evolving over the scale of billions of years, and Eukaryotes weren't always around, it took a long time for microbes to develop the traits we see today.

Comment: If you wish to address comments to individuals other than the person whose contribution you are commenting on you need to add an @joebloggs to alert him to the fact that the comment is addressed to him. All I can say is that it seems to me that your interest isn't in the chemistry or biochemistry of the evolution of iron metabolism, as your question implies, but rather whether it could provide another example of a change of functionality from the change in a single amino acid. A pity, because the question in your title is interesting, but it requires a knowledge of chemistry to address.

Comment: It really doesn't require chemistry at this point, it more or less requires a single date or a yes/no with evidence to support it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Cyanobacteria require iron for photosynthesis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123943132000032) and can be found as fossil stromatolites dating back to 3.5 billion years ago.  Stromatolites are layered structures made up of cyanobacteria and sediment.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stromatolite

Modern stromatolites can be found at Shark Bay in Australia, Chetumal Bay in Belize, and Laguna Bacalar in the Yucatan Peninsula.

Cyanobacteria are also believed to have evolved into the first microbes to produce oxygen by photosynthesis, which was a catalyst for the [Great Oxygenation Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event) which occurred around 2.45 billion years ago.

Comment: So you're saying life nearly started out as cyanobacteria? This would have to be quite a recent development because I've seen multiple sources in the past say cyanobacteria didn't form until around 2.7 BYA.

Comment: @John Joe: Sorry, I thought I had provided this source also.  http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/bacteria/cyanofr.html

Comment: So if that's true, why was it only much later that the atmosphere became oxygenated?

Comment: While I largely agree with this answer, I'd point out that as far as I know we have of knowing how similar the metabolism of these ancient organisms was to extant organisms. There's evidence of morphological similarity but morphological similarity does not necessarily imply biochemical similarity.

Comment: So if life already had the capacity to harness iron, why didn't life forms release that oxygen earlier?

Comment: @JohnJoe This is discussed in the Wikipedia article on the great oxygenation Event: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxygenation_Event#Time_lag_theory - it would have been released but was not yet able to build up.

Comment: @JohnJoe if you need to ask a separate question I'd post it as such, not add it in the comments; the answer above fully answers what you actually asked in the body of your question (although your title and question body include different questions).

Comment: I guess it all makes sense then. I was just surprised that more developed bacteria appeared that early on contrary to what I thought other sources had suggested, but thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**

It has been proposed that iron was indeed important for the first life on earth, specifically in combination with sulphur. This is because conditions are thought to have existed in volcanic hydrothermal vents that would have allowed formation of iron–sulphur complexes which perform oxido-reduction reactions in modern proteins (as well as more sophisticated functions). Some system for oxido-reduction of chemical compounds is required for life to develop, and the inorganic simplicity of Fe–S clusters, together with their ability to interact with the backbone of proteins, argues for their early involvement, rather than the chemically more elaborate NAD and FAD.

**The Archaean Environment**

One theory suggests that life  originated volcanic hydrothermal conditions in which the oxidation of iron minerals by hydrogen sulphide would have been possible. It has even been suggested that life originated on the surface of iron sulphides (the [‘Iron–sulphur world hypothesis’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%E2%80%93sulfur_world_hypothesis)), although this answer is more modest in its scope.

**Iron–Sulphur Metalloclusters**

Modern proteins contain a range of iron-sulphur clusters of varying complexity, but it has been argued in a review in Science by [Rees and Howard](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/300/5621/929.full.pdf) that the simplest of these — the 2Fe:2S cluster in, e.g. ferredoxin — could have evolved in the conditions mentioned above.

[image: FeS clusters]

*[Different FeS clusters. Note that the external yellow sulphur atoms are from cysteine side-chains of the protein. (Adapted from a review by [Johnson et al. (2005)](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.biochem.74.082803.133518))]*

**Interaction of Iron–Sulphur Clusters with Proteins**

In some iron-containing proteins, like cytochrome *c*, the iron is held in place by a sophisticated organic molecule (haem) and interacts with amino acid side-chains. However in simple iron–sulphur clusters interaction with the NH groups of the protein backbone (in special conformations — [‘nests’](https://www.gla.ac.uk/projects/originoflife/html/2001/pdf_files/MilnerWhite.pdf) and [‘crowns’](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/prot.24923)) can occur. Thus initially they could have been acquired by simpler proteins, which some believe to have preceded the development of those with the side-chains to provide more sophisticated interaction.

[image: FeS interaction with the protein backbone]

*[Interaction of FeS clusters with protein backbone NH groups (blue): A. [‘nest’](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283601952271), B. [‘crown’](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/prot.24923) with the N atoms in space-filling mode.]*

**Other Contemporary Redox Cofactors**

The intellectual appeal of Fe–S cofactors as being evolutionarily most ancient can be seen if one compares them with the structures of other contemporary redox cofactors (images taken from [Berg *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22576/)):

[image: NAD and FAD]

It has been argued that the adenine and ribose moieties of these cofactors attest to an ancient origin — in the supposed [RNA world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world) — an idea that I, personally, find appealing. Nevertheless, their emergence would require a mechanism for the synthesis of their functional organic components — nicotinamide and flavin, respectively. In contrast, Fe–S clusters come ‘ready made’.

**More Complex Iron–Sulphur Clusters**

Iron sulphur clusters are also found in the [nitrogenase protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogenase), which converts nitrogen gas to ammonia. This must be a very ancient protein, but its greater complexity (the cluster includes molybdenum) suggests it may have arisen later. Another elaboration is proteins, such as [aconitase](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22427/#A2394), that have Fe–S clusters linked by more complex organic groups.

[image: More complex Fe proteins]

*[Iron-containing proteins of greater complexity. Haem, the non-sulphur iron prosthetic group of cytochromes etc. is also shown. Adapted from [Berg et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/)]*

**Iron in Photosynthesis**

As mentioned by @Kurt, iron is a component of photosystem II in contemporary cyanobacteria. However [photosystem II](http://www.nature.com/articles/nsmb.1559.pdf) is extremely complex and the precise chemical basis of the non-haem iron requirement is currently unclear. Although perhaps necessary if cyanobacterial photosynthesis were responsible for the great oxygenation, this complexity would suggest a relatively late emergence in the pre-aerobic era.

Comment: I have expanded my answer, which is now essentially complete, unless anyone requires details of the metabolic pathways aluded to, which I will be happy to provide.

Comment: I think if this was hybridized with the first answer it would have made both better, because the first answer showed that the same premise of cellular respiration took place much earlier than thought with direct physical evidence which explains iron and its role but without much theory, whereas you mainly rely on a conjecture of a specific compound and not direct evidence so much. They "can" interact with background proteins, but did that actually make them necessary? Was there actually a mutation back then that lead microbes to incorporate a modern organelle or metabolite from that compound?

Comment: Any statement about metabolism in early evolution depends on deduction rather than physical evidence. The argument of @Kurt could be restated as: contemporary cyanobacteria require iron (for PSII); they are thought to have caused the great oxygenation; hence iron must have been used in metabolism before aerobic life. The argument assumes that photosynthesis in ancient cyanobacteria was the same as today. His photo is only evidence for the existence of cyanobacteria even earlier, but if they had the current PSII they would still be far more elaborate than anything in “the first life on earth”.

Comment: Like I said if there was a way to combine both answers I would be open to it, but it's not mere speculation if we can actually see the imprints of the structure of microorganisms. It does assume the same photosynthesis, but it assumes that because there is consistent material evidence for it, whereas your argument is "well, this compound could have been involved because it could have interacted..." and that's why it's called a "hypothesis."